# if condition, loop in grep

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, grep

Could someone please provide help for me.

I tried to start writing a shell script but am getting hung up with this issue.
I need to `grep` commands "adb shell ps" and find in it 3 processes with names:

1. proc1
2. proc2
3. proc3

And if these processes are present in the `grep` output, then continue work with the script, else check the `grep` 5 times within the interval - 30 seconds.  Finally - if my process doesn't start, just exit form script.

Comment: Can you clarify what's  the question?
You need to find 'adb shell ps' in proc1/2/3 logs or what? Is the process the one you're checking or process's logs ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a script that does what I think you're looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

cnt=1; found=0;
while [ "$cnt" -le 5 ]; do
  echo "chk#: $cnt"
  if [[ $(pgrep -f "proc1") && $(pgrep -f "proc2") && $(pgrep -f "proc3") ]]; then
    found=1
    break
  fi
  let cnt=cnt+1
  sleep 6
done

[ "$found" -eq 0 ] && exit

echo "found them"
```

You can change this line out if the proc1, proc2, & proc3 are the actual names of the processes. The above looks for any occurrence of those strings in the command lines.

```
  if [[ $(pgrep "proc1") && $(pgrep "proc2") && $(pgrep "proc3") ]]; then
```

The script makes use of `pgrep` instead of `grep` since this command can essentially do a `ps .. | grep ...` in a single command.